# Submit a job to be run on several nodes on a partition that disallows it

Tags: slurm, lammps

I use LAMMPS. Usually I use the following slurm job file to submit jobs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name=lammps
#SBATCH --begin=now
#SBATCH --nodes=4
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32
#SBATCH --partition=medium
srun -u lmp_mpi -in in.file
```

Partition `medium` allows jobs up to 4-node size, partition `small` allows jobs that are only 1-node size. Is it possible to run one 4-node-sized job on `small` partition? Probably using several job submissions, but LAMMPS must run like it was launched under one 4-node-sized job.